# sendmail in trac no worky

Tags: email, notifications, sendmail, trac

`Trac` does not appear to be triggering an email event when submitting a change to a ticket with a cc'ed email address.  I currently have logging enabled, and I'm not finding anything pertaining to email in the trac.log file.   I'm also monitoring /var/log/maillog - nothing appears there either.

I am not using SMTP.   I'm attempting to configure `Trac` to use `sendmail`.

My current [notifications] section:

```
admit_domains = 
always_notify_owner = false
always_notify_reporter = false
always_notify_updater = true
email_sender = SmtpEmailSender
ignore_domains = 
mime_encoding = none
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
smtp_always_bcc = known_good_address@domain.tld
smtp_always_cc = 
smtp_default_domain = 
smtp_enabled = false
smtp_from = trac@localhost
smtp_from_name = 
smtp_password = 
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = trac@localhost
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user = 
ticket_subject_template = $prefix #$ticket.id: $summary
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
```

Path to sendmail is correct:

```
[box]# which sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Should all of the smtp references be removed from the trac.ini [notification] section in order for Trac's sendmail hook to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as easy as changing

```
smtp_enabled = false
```

to

```
smtp_enabled = true
```

Comment: Why would I need to *enable* smtp when I'm attempting to use sendmail instead?

Comment: @acoder- I believe Trac triggers off of that field to determine whether or not to send email.  When sendmail support was added, they never went back and renamed the field.